# Why do people keep their employment details, such as how much they make, secret?

Tags: job-search, salary, confidentiality, government

After finishing school I had trouble finding work. I applied to a government agency that was supposed to help with the job search. I found they gave me the run around and didn't help much. I managed to get a temporary job recently :) I told my case worker at the agency I can't attend a scheduled meeting with him because I have work. He is now saying he needs information from me like pay, position, company, work hours etc.

I know it's common for people to try to keep such information private. Why is this? Is it just considered polite or is it strategic for career advancement?

Is there ever a legitimate reason to need/want to know this?

**EDIT** the main question is why do people keep their employment details secret. The story about the case worker asking is a specific example, so I don't see them as entirely separate questions.

Comment: A question "why do you need such information" should be directed at your case manager.

Comment: I feel the two questions you are asking are completely different. If you feel the case manager didn't help with your job search, just tell him the truth. "You didn't really help me, therefore I'm not telling you anything." That being said, is that really the case? Maybe an avenue doesn't pan out, but it doesn't mean that they didn't try to help you. Personally, I try to be grateful to everyone who took the time to help me, whether their help was useful or not. Secrecy, in this case, is not really advantage to you, it only makes you appear resentful.

Comment: What was the name of the government agency? Was this agency local, or was it part of the regional or national government? Did this agency provide unemployment benefits while you were looking?

Comment: Is your question "why is the case manager asking?" the answers could be for a report, or because they have something for you that pays more, or pure curiosity. But your title is "why do people keep this secret?" which is the opposite question. Pick one.

Comment: In the United States, there are *hard laws* about disclosing that sort of information!

Answer (score 5):

**If it is high, people get jealous.**

I am a software developer and one who recently graduated from university. I don't think it is a surprise that software developers get paid relatively well. Queue the pile of fellow grads in other fields who think that people like myself are overpaid for our experience level while they earn far less as baristas or entry-level generic business staff.

Also, if you are good, there is a decent chance that you are outearning a lot of your experience in years peers even within the industry or are at least a lot closer in pay than you would normally be to them.  That is not the kind of thing you want to reveal.

**If it is low, people think you aren't that great.**

I don't earn as much gross as I would in some other cities in Canada. I had offers for more there. However, factoring in various things and I would actually be $10,000 to $20,000 behind. Plenty of my friends have compared the gross software salaries between cities and have openly wondered whether I am a relative idiot for not taking a job there instead. Has it hurt their perception of me? Almost certainly.

> Why would the government want (aka need) to know this?

Could be anything from statistical record-keeping to determining whether you are still eligible to job search assistance. Maybe it is for them to claim credit for helping you find work to boost their statistics. Generally, the government knows your salary anyway because that would need to be reported, but this might vary by country.

Comment: "The government" is not a single entity here. Data protection laws prohibit data sharing between unemployment assistance and the tax office in most countries, so gathering meaningful statistical data is hard.

Answer (score 2):

The case worker needs to close the case, even if they weren't the ones responsible for you landing the job, so they have a form to fill out that asks for these details.

These are run through various statistics internally, to find out what measures were successful in bringing people towards employment, with the goal of ending measures that cause people to reappear in the system within a few months (such as sending them to work in outbound call centers) and doing things instead that work longer-term.

Your case is a bit of an outlier there, since it cannot be traced back to a specific measure they've taken, so it doesn't affect these statistics much.

A second set of statistics they run on the data is a correlation of people's skill sets with the salary they receive later on, which helps them classify applicants, and companies. If someone with similar answers as yours on the skills questionnaire comes along, they have a rough idea what kind of jobs this person could apply to, and what salary to expect there.

This is more important for lower-paid jobs, where the job center might find out that it is a better investment in the long run to pay for a school than to have the applicant work a minimum-wage job -- but it's still useful information for higher-paid jobs as well.

Last but not least, if you ever file for unemployment again, it will show up in your file as "found themselves a good job after a while", which will give the (new) case worker an impression that you can be trusted to look on your own and you don't need to be hassled as much.

Comment: +1 this question is about why the government job search agency wants this info, not why you shouldn't talk about it at a cocktail party.

Answer (score 1):

I guess since all other answers were downvoted, people are missing a relation to the question.

> I know it's common for people to try to keep such information private.

Where I work, working hours and position are not a secret as far as I know discussions about work.
Payment indeed is.

Let's look at examples, that can be extended according to personal opinions.

#### Why would you make public what you earn?

- Beause topic comes to salary and one doesn't mind to reveal own salary and one is not afraid of or is not thinking about things listed in "why keep secret".
- To compare salary to colleagues or friends in a serious way. Then again, one either isn't aware of or isn't afraid of reasons to not do so, mentioned below.
- Bragging if one is - or thinks to be - paid over average, without someone being interested in it.
- Trying to make the employer bad if one is paid under average.

The last two bullets can badly backfire and damage reputation.

#### Why would you keep secret what you earn?

- Avoid someone become jealous - others or yourself.
- No matter if you are paid well or bad, all you will get is not appreciation or anything helpful but annoying phrases. *"Why don't you do X, you could afford it"* or *"why do you still work there for that money"* or a variety of other stuff that you don't need.

#### Why would your employer want you to keep secret what you earn?

- To avoid jealousy - it can have bad effects on the workplace and employees' mood.
- To not have constant discussions like "X gets more than me but works less" and stuff.
- To not allow conclusions on monthly expenses and thus be predictable.

> Why would the government want (aka need) to know this?

First of all, I'd just write them you have found a job on your own (don't emphasize that much, but note it) and any more effort of the agency is not necessary, thank you for helping. Then see if they still want to know more.
If so, ask them what for.

Discuss with your employer if it's ok to tell your income to the authorities. Consider some authorities do know your income anyway, for taxes and whatever else. If this department really needs to know your income, they are not 'everyone' else and shouldn't it publish to the rest of the world.

Comment: I disagree with your view that making your salary public is a bad character trait. Being able to compare one's salary to others' is vital information to navigate the job market, and the reason companies want you to keep that information secret is so they get a steady supply of applicants who don't know what they can ask for, and to stop their employees from forming unions -- the most common reaction to finding out that one of our peers is paid less is to ask the company to raise their salary to match ours.

Comment: @SimonRichter I summed up things why someone would reveal salary to others. There is a difference if it's done anonymously in a survey or personally to somebody. I didn't mean to talk about salary is bad character in general. Yes there are reasons to just talk normally about it and I think it's time to edit my answer to make this clear.

Comment: There is no need to discuss with your employer whether it is OK to tell an employment official what you earn.

Answer (score 1):

> I know it's common for people to try to keep such information private.
>   Why is this? Is it just considered polite or is it strategic for
>   career advancement?

This attitude has been established for the convenience of employers. It makes management easier, and improves their bargaining position when negotiating salaries: management knows what they're paying for equivalent workers and the employees don't. It's the same reason that car salespeople work very hard to keep pricing of cars obscure: there's the sticker price and then there's the "real" price.

Open knowledge of compensation can genuinely make management harder. Employees may second-guess management judgments about the relative value of employees, and it may inspire jealously and hard feelings among employees. However, secrecy of compensation enables cronyism and [egregious wage discrimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilly_Ledbetter), so pick your poison.

I spent several years working as a public employee. All of our compensation was a matter of public record. It never seemed to be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it just considered polite or is it strategic for career
>   advancement?

Plenty of solid reasons, the most general is this is the information age, info is valuable and shouldn't be given away for nothing.

But pay and things like that are between you and an employer. In terms of job searching it weakens your negotiating stance for people to know your current remuneration. You should inform them of how much you WANT to be making in order to work for them, not giving them what you make now.

Likewise with colleagues, I consistently negotiated quite a bit more than I thought my colleagues were making and never informed anyone because there was no benefit to me in doing so. In one case I afterwards learnt I was making more than double the other senior engineers. If they had known that at the time, it would have caused management and perhaps myself quite a bit of grief.